# Two definitions of compact set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am reading parallely two books on analysis, and they have two different definitions of compact set:
1) Subset A of metric space X is called compact, if every open cover of A contains a *finite* subcover.
2) Subset A of metric space X is called compact, if from every sequence of point in A you can choose convergent sequence with limit in A.

Is there any proof which shows equivalence of these definitions? I don't even imagine where to begin constructing proof.

Comment: Here is a [reference](http://math.berkeley.edu/~jdahl/141/141sc.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first definition is that of *compactness* while the second definition is for *sequential compactness*. For a general topological space, the two notions do not coincide, but for metric spaces they do. A proof of the equivalence between the two definitions in this setting can be found in most topology books (for example, Theorem 28.2 of Munkres' *Topology*, second edition). There are also many websites which contain the relevant information, such as [this one](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequentially_Compact_Metric_Space_is_Compact).